# Use function to remove divs after a sepecified div

Tags: javascript, html

*HTML*:

```
<div class="page">111111</div>
<div class="page">222222</div>
<div class="page">333333</div>
<div class="page">444444</div>
<div class="page">555555</div>
```

*JavaScript*:

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("page");
for (i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    bt = document.createElement("button");
    bt.innerHTML = "kill my followings";
    div[i].appendChild(bt);
    bt.onclick = function (i) {
        return function () {
            kill(div[i]);
        }
    }(i);
}

function kill(obj) {
    // ...
}
```

See [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/helisz/BtSKJ/2/) here.

I constructed some divs which `class="page"`. I used JavaScript to add buttons to each div, and add `onClick` event to each of them.

I need to remove the divs after my current operating div. e.g, If user click button in No.3 div, No.4 and 5 should be removed.
How to realized it?

(if not necessary, the structure of original html is not allowed to change)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be the simplest way to go:

```
function kill(obj) {
    while (obj.nextSibling) {
        obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj.nextSibling);
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/BtSKJ/3/